# Cannot start ubuntu-desktop

Tags: server, gui

I am mainly a Windows technician and am trying to install Ubuntu server. Everything worked fine and I can log in using the shell but when I installed `ubuntu-desktop` it just refuses to start.

I did try `startx` and got the message: "server already running"

I tried "start gdm" (what is this supposed to do?) and it comes back with: "Job is already running: gdm"

I know that the server version is not really meant for use with `ubuntu-desktop` but all our other servers are like that and I want it. Is there any help out there?

The server is running on a VM install that my IT department made for me and I connect to the machine shell using Tera Ter Web 3.1.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps, if you use **gdm** it should be GNOME.
With `ubuntu-desktop` correctly more using of **lightdm** and Unity.

I haven't experience with *server* version. But it looks like popular trouble with **home** folder permissions.

Once I was it done by just running Guest session, unlock administrator account, remove it, and create new one.

Other alternative:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall -f -m -u gdm
sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm
```

Select **gdm**

```
sudo restart gdm
```

Same way appropriate also for **lightdm** ((use `lightdm` ***instead*** `gdm`))